# RegEx: How to match a whole string with fixed-length region with negative look ahead conditions that are overriden afterwards?

Tags: regex, match

The strings I parse with a regular expression contain a region of fixed length `N` where there can either be numbers or dashes. However, if a dash occurs, only dashes are allowed to follow for the rest of the region. After this region, numbers, dashes, and letters are allowed to occur.

Examples (`N=5`, starting at the beginning):

```
12345ABC
12345123
1234-1
1234--1
1----1AB
```

How can I correctly match this? I currently am stuck at something like `(?:\d|-(?!\d)){5}[A-Z0-9\-]+` (for `N=5`), but I cannot make numbers work directly following my region if a dash is present, as the negative look ahead blocks the match.

**Update**
Strings that should *not* be matched (`N=5`)

```
1-2-3-A
----1AB
--1--1A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assert that the first 5 characters are either digits or `-` and make sure that there is no - before a digit in the first 5 chars.

```
^(?![\d-]{0,3}-\d)(?=[\d-]{5})[A-Z\d-]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![\d-]{0,3}-\d)` Make sure that in the first 5 chars there is no `-` before a digit
- `(?=[\d-]{5})` Assert at least 5 digits or `-`
- `[A-Z\d-]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed characters
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g7gcij/1)

If [atomic groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) are available:

```
^(?=[\d-]{5})(?>\d+-*|-{5})[A-Z\d_]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[\d-]{5})` Assert at least 5 chars `-` or digit
- `(?>` Atomic group

  - `\d+-*` Match 1+ digits and optional `-`
  - `|` or
  - `-{5}` match 5 times `-`
- `)` Close atomic group
- `[A-Z\d_]*` Match optional chars A-Z digit or `_`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPTinb/1)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this does not obey the condition that a single dash within the region prohibits any following digits within. I updated the question with some examples of strings not to match.

Comment: @fbindel Did you check the latest update? https://regex101.com/r/JxbIuM/1/

Comment: Your updates do help and match everything, thank you. I lack the reputation to upvote or accept an answer. What I do not understand: playing around with these expressions, I see that the `+` or `*` at the end are necessary for a match even if only a single character follows my region (i. e. `123--A` is only matched by your answer if the `+` before `$` is left intact). This surprises me. Why is there a difference between matching at least once (`+`) and exactly once?

Comment: @fbindel In the first expression, the first 2 parts are assertions that do not match( consume) characters. If those assertions are both true, then this part `[A-Z\d-]+` actually consumes 1 or more characters. In the second expression, there are already either 5 dashes or digits followed by dashes matched, and the `[A-Z\d_]*` matches optional characters from the character class so that exactly 5 chars are also matched.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-word-boundary assertion `\B`:

```
^[-\d](?:-|\B\d){4}[A-Z\d-]*$
```

A non word-boundary succeeds at a position between two word characters (from `\w` ie `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) or two non-word characters (from `\W` ie `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`). *(and also between a non-word character and the limit of the string)*

With it, each `\B\d` always follows a digit. (and can't follow a dash)

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/1DktYi/1)

---

Other way (if lookbehinds are allowed):

```
^\d*-*(?<=^.{5})[A-Z\d-]*$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/SavX7V/1)

Comment: I never tried `\B`. That's an interesting way of doing it and works well with my set of strings. I will keep it in mind, thank you. (I cannot currently upvote or accept an answer)